# Is there a way to show another form on a button click than continue with default action only after the user clicks "Yes" using JS only

Tags: javascript, html

I have to do following:

- When the user clicks a button show a modal which has another form
- In the new modal form ask a question to the user.
- If the user clicks yes, continue with the default action for the
  previous form.
- If the user clicks no, stop the default action for the previous form.
- This should work for both "**button**" and "**submit**" types of buttons.
- I am not allowed to edit/change the HTML on the page. All of the
  above must be done using JavaScript only.

Is it possible to do something like this? If so, what technologies/keyword should i search for it? I spent 3+ hours on google and I still have no idea.

I could manage to stop the "button" form working. On the other hand, the "submit" ones keep working no matter what I tried.

Comment: You will likely need to use `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()`. This might point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263327/delaying-default-events-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the modal on pressing 'yes' with

```
document.getElementById("modal").style.display="none";
```

And when pressing 'no' you could redirect the user to a url inside of your website

```
window.location.replace("https://domain.test");
```

If you want to prevent the default action for a submit button you could try

```
document.getElementById("submitbutton").preventDefault();
```